# MySQL Проверка существования записи в связанной таблице по двум полям

Tags: mysql

Есть главная таблица, у нее есть две связи с двумя другими таблицами (обе многие-ко-многим с дополнительными связующими таблицами). Нужно вывести такие записи из главной таблицы, данные о которых есть в одной связующей таблице (+ условие, что связь будет с определенной строкой связанной таблицы) и данных о которых нет в другой связующей таблице, но так же только в определенной строчке.
Другими словами, есть таблица с лекарствами, в другой таблице грибковые заболевания, которые лечатся этими лекарствами, а в третьей таблице болезни, которые могут быть противопоказаниями к этим лекарствам. Запрос должен выводить те лекарства, которые лечат один конкретный грибок, но при этом не являются противопоказаны, если есть одно или несколько из введенных заболеваний.

Для первого условия работает это

```
 SELECT pma.name_eng AS "Название",  pma_efficiency.efficiency AS "Эффективность в отношении грибка"
     FROM pma.pma 
 JOIN pma.pma_efficiency ON pma.pma.pma_id = pma.pma_efficiency.pma_id  
    JOIN pma.fungi ON pma.pma_efficiency.fungi_id = pma.fungi.fungi_id 
     WHERE  first_name LIKE "%Candida%" AND second_name LIKE "%albicans%" ORDER BY efficiency;
```

А со вторым проблемы... Такой вариант не подходит

```
LEFT JOIN pma.pma_contraindication ON pma.pma_id = pma.pma_contraindication.pma_id 
 LEFT JOIN   pma.desease ON pma.pma_contraindication.desease_id = pma.desease.desease_id
 WHERE pma_contraindication.desease_id!=(SELECT desease_id FROM pma.desease WHERE desease_name="%Пиелонефрит%")
```

В общем, вопрос в том, как проверить отсутствие связи между двумя строчками из таблиц, связанных связью многие-ко-многим.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде дошло. Может, и криво все вместе, но у меня пока работает такой вариант `(pma_contraindication.desease_id != ALL(SELECT desease.desease_id FROM pma.desease WHERE desease.desease_name LIKE "Пиелонефрит" OR desease.desease_name LIKE "почечная недостаточность") OR pma_contraindication.pma_id IS NULL)`

Comment: Как вариант, во втором `left join` в `on` сразу задаете условия отбора записей (like '...') и     в where проверяете единственное условие `pma.desease.desease_id is NULL`